# Convert menu to tab with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with tabs, but the active tabs doesn't merge with the `background`, so it's not a real tab. How can i apply the `border white` to the active tab so it looks like it merges with the content background, but without deleting the top grey border of the content background?

Main structure:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/#">ArqOS Scheduler</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="nodes.html">Nodes</a></li>
        <li  class="active"><a href="tasks.html">Tasks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">blabalbla the content</div>
```

For a better understanding, see my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/La36c/1/
**Note**: You need to enlarge the width, otherwise you'll see the mobile version of the menu!

Comment: When do you need the changes in the background? in the hover event or when your item is selected?

Comment: Only when the li item has the class active, so i need to put the white border in the bottom of the active tab for merging with the background white, because now i have a grey border that splits the background with the tabs.

Comment: did you tried add the class into the selected div?

Comment: Yeah but the grey border of the background splits the active tab! I want the grey border of the background but without split the active tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could do this little thing with `.active:before`:

```css
.active:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I've made an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La36c/3/) for you